# CompletableFuture allOF, missing results the result list

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, completable-future

I'm experiencing a bad problem...
My spring boot application reads a large file and almost for each file row produces an xml.
The process of producing xmls is thought to be multithreading. Actually, I have an async method which takes as parameter a piece of the file at time, does some business logic and returns a list of xmls in byte[] in a completableFuture.

This is the method:

```
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<byte[]>> genereteXmlsWithMultithreading(RigheCorrelate righeCorrelate) {

        unitaConversioneInXml.setRecordTypeANABI((RecordTypeANABI) serialize(righeCorrelate.getRigaANABI()));
        unitaConversioneInXml.setRecordTypeT07((RecordTypeTypeT) serialize(righeCorrelate.getRigaT()));

        List<byte[]> xmlFilesPerTask = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        for (String rigaQ : righeCorrelate.getRigheQ()) {

            unitaConversioneInXml.setRecordTypeQ((RecordTypeTypeQ) serialize(rigaQ));

            try {
                xmlFilesPerTask.add(XmlUtils.generateXml(unitaConversioneInXml.mapToXmlClass(), jaxbContext));

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Errore nella generazione di un file xml", e);
            }

        }

        log.info("Elaborati ".concat(String.valueOf(xmlFilesPerTask.size())).concat(" xmls"));
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(xmlFilesPerTask);
    }
```

As you can see, the method retrun a CompletableFuture of List<byte[]>.

The I put together all the xml lists containing the produced xmls by each thread in a service class:

```
List<CompletableFuture<List<byte[]>>> completableFutures = readFile(files[0]);
                CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
                CompletableFuture<List<byte[]>> combinedFuture = allFutures.thenApply(v -> completableFutures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                xmlFiles = combinedFuture.get();
```

Here the method readFile reads one file and returns the list of all CompletableFuture.

Now, the problem is that the produces xmls should not have duplicates. This is because the file does not have duplicate rows. But the result is that I have some duplicates xmls and some other are missing. What I mean is that some file rows seems not have been converted to xml. This is not possibile, however, since debugging the application I know that each unique row has been passed in the object 'righeCorrelate' of type RigheCorrelate. That is, the async method receives as paramenter only different rows.
So, I am pretty sure that the problem is not reading the file or the file itself.

Is it possible that when I put together all lists o byte[] I lost some elaborated records?

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Thanks

Comment: did you try to run it without stream? 
like after receiving a list of  completableFutures  you run a `for` loop?

Comment: Hi @DavidA., thanks for your suggestion. I tried and.. it worked! 
for(CompletableFuture<List<byte[]>> completableFuture : completableFutures){
                    xmlFiles.addAll(completableFuture.get());
                }.
I did a get of the result for each iterazion. I wonder if this is correct in terms of multithreanding. What do you think?

Comment: @Seveio I am glad that worked, i dont have the full code, so, try to understand how `stream` works and understand where its failing.
Meanwhile, the approach is good, and I would recommend to use `completableFuture.join()` in order to wait to finish (while working in background).
Please pay attention that @Async doesn't work with private method.

Comment: Also in order to help you, you could print the thread name in the async function

Comment: Many thanks @DavidA. Answer the question in the answer section and I will accept your answer

Comment: I tried using the join method anyway, and the result fail... it seems the problem is the join method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many factors that can go wrong.

Therefore, I recommend making a few changes to the code:

- Take out the Stream, go to for loop
- Puts logs in the asynchronized function with the name of the Thread
- Monitor the memory.

Good luck!